# regular expression to extract foo, bar, baz and logical operator

Tags: php, regex

String Parsing

```
foo_and_bar_and_baz_or_doe
```

expected result: foo, bar, baz and doe along with and, and and or.

i tried `/(.*?)(_and_|_or_)/i` but its skipping last one.

actually sting is

```
having_tag_slugs_and_having_category1_slug_and_having_category2_slug_or_having_category3_slug
```

out put, i am looking is

```
having_tag_slugs
having_category1_slug
having_category2_slug
having_category3_slug

_and_
_and_
_or_
''
```

Comment: Why not use `explode`?

Comment: So are you just looking to remove `_` from the string?

Comment: Your regex unconditionally requires the match to end with `_and_` or `_or_` so no wonder it doesn't match the last part which doesn't.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve (and why)

Comment: @BartFriederichs i cant explode coz my real string is different not only _

Comment: @JapanPro, you can explode with a string, like `explode("_and_", $str)`. You can even adher to boolean preference like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regular expression -

```
/(.*?)(_and_|_or_|$)/im
```

Hope that helps. Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: if i want to have and and or first in that case /(_and_|_or_|$)?(.*?)/im

Answer (score 1):

```
$a="foo_and_bar_and_baz_or_doe";
$c=explode("_",$a);
print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$str = 'having_tag_slugs_and_having_category1_slug_and_having_category2_slug_or_having_category3_slug';
$arr = preg_split('/(_and_|_or_)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => having_tag_slugs
    [1] => _and_
    [2] => having_category1_slug
    [3] => _and_
    [4] => having_category2_slug
    [5] => _or_
    [6] => having_category3_slug
)
```